# How to use QPen with QpainterPath?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a code like:

```
     QPainterPath groupPath;
     QPen pen; // new

     pen.setCosmetic(1); // new

     groupPath.setPen(pen); // error (error: class "QPainterPath" has no member "setPen")
     groupPath.moveTo(60.0, 40.0);
     groupPath.arcTo(40.0, 35.0, 40.0, 10.0, 180.0, 180.0);
     groupPath.moveTo(40.0, 40.0);
     groupPath.lineTo(40.0, 80.0);
     groupPath.arcTo(40.0, 75.0, 40.0, 10.0, 0.0, 180.0);
     groupPath.lineTo(80.0, 80.0);
     groupPath.lineTo(80.0, 40.0);
     groupPath.closeSubpath();
```

How can I use setPen to use Cosmetic in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `setPen()` on a `QPainterPath` because it's not a *painter*, it's just a *path*.

You should create a `QPainter`, use `setPen()` on it, and then draw the path :

```
QPainter painter(this);
QPen pen;
pen.setCosmetic(true);
painter.setPen(pen);

QPainterPath groupPath
groupPath.moveTo(60.0, 40.0);
groupPath.arcTo(40.0, 35.0, 40.0, 10.0, 180.0, 180.0);
groupPath.moveTo(40.0, 40.0);
groupPath.lineTo(40.0, 80.0);
groupPath.arcTo(40.0, 75.0, 40.0, 10.0, 0.0, 180.0);
groupPath.lineTo(80.0, 80.0);
groupPath.lineTo(80.0, 40.0);
groupPath.closeSubpath();

painter.drawPath(groupPath);
```

Also, as *@Andreas* said, `pen.setCosmetic(true)` is not needed, because the default constructor of `QPen()` creates a pen of width `0`, which is already *Cosmetic*.

Comment: and how can I add the painter to my scene if my drawing is related to a special scene object?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your actual issue is, but some remarks:

- Actually `QPen::setCosmetic()` expects a `bool` parameter; `1` would work, but `true` would be correct.
- Newly created `QPen`s have a **width of 0** when created through the default constructor
- `QPen`s with width 0 are **cosmetic by default**

Hence, `pen.setCosmetic(true)` will not have any effect, your pen should be cosmetic (means, have the same width independant of the scale factor) anyway.

And, finally, as @zakinster mentioned, `QPainterPath` does not have a `setPen()` method.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I get an error when I use a setPen function (error: class "QPainterPath" has no member "setPen"
). Then I could at least try `false` to see the effect.